# Rendering a component using ngClass

Tags: angular

I have an stand alone component and I want to render it in another component using ngClass. It doesn't work, if I use a variable to specify the name of the class. Does anyone know what can be the problem? Here is my code:

hello.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
    standalone: true
})
export class HelloComponent {

}
```

hello.component.html:

```
<p> Hello World!</p>
```

app.component.ts:

```
component: string = 'hello'
```

app.component.html:

```
<div [ngClass]="component"></div>
```

Comment: You are calling to a component named "component", not to the component variable content. Have you tried `[ngClass]="{{component}}"` or `[ngClass] ={{component}}`?

Comment: @BraveOtter using `{{}}` doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

ngClass is only for dynamic styling and not for component rendering.
Instead, you need to use the Angular Dynamic Component Loader mechanism.

1. define placeholder:

```html
    <ng-template #dynamicComponentPlaceholder></ng-template>
```

2. Load the Component Dynamically

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('dynamicComponentPlaceholder', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicComponentPlaceholder: ViewContainerRef;

      constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.loadDynamicComponent();
      }

      loadDynamicComponent() {
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent);
        const viewContainerRef = this.dynamicComponentPlaceholder;
        viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import CommonModule for ngClass to work.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    imports: [CommonModule],
    templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
    standalone: true
})
export class HelloComponent {

}
```

Comment: importing `CommomModule` doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @user6781 can you check once if you saved the ts file and also try to print in html by doing <div [ngClass]="component">{{component}}</div>

Comment: This will show the value of `component` which is hello (we need to render `Hello World!`)